# How to add an Eventlistener to an instance method

Tags: javascript, canvas, ecmascript-6, addeventlistener

I have a class in which I want to run a function whenever an event occurs. Whenever the function calls, the function of the instance of the class does not run.

```js
class Player {
    constructor() {
        window.addEventListener('keypress', this.key_press);
        this.keys_pressed = 0;
    }

    key_press(key_press) {
        if(key_press.key == "w") {
            console.log(key_press);
            this.keys_pressed += 1;
        }
        console.log(this.keys_pressed);
    }
}
```

Whenever `this.key_press` is called, it logs out NaN. It seems as though the method of the class isn't being run, but rather a copy(?). I've also tried running another instance function inside `key_press()` but it says that the function is undefined.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As per my view NaN is coming from this line `console.log(this.keys_pressed);` while your code is working fine. Check here : https://jsfiddle.net/manektech/g8qzs0vm/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are adding an event listener to the `window` or any element of the DOM, the `this` value points to that element instead of the `Player` instance.

So you are getting `NaN` as the `window` does not have the `keys_pressed` property and `keys_pressed += 1` is treated as `keys_pressed = undefined + 1` which is `NaN`.

To fix this we need to `bind` to the `Player` instance explicitly:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#input");
class Player {
    constructor() {
        input.addEventListener('keypress', this.key_press.bind(this));
        this.keys_pressed = 0;
    }

    key_press(key_press) {
        if(key_press.key == "w") {
            this.keys_pressed += 1;
        }
        console.log(this.keys_pressed);
    }
}
let p = new Player();
```

```html
Type here: <input type="text" id="input">
```

We can also use an *arrow* `( => )` function which captures the `this` from the current context and would point to the current instance of the `Player` object:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#input");
class Player {
    constructor() {
        input.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => this.key_press(event));
        this.keys_pressed = 0;
    }

    key_press(key_press) {
        if(key_press.key == "w") {
            this.keys_pressed += 1;
        }
        console.log(this.keys_pressed);
    }
}
let p = new Player();
```

```html
Type here: <input type="text" id="input">
```

Comment: @Sealestr Please accept this answer, if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another workaround with onkeypress and bind.

```js
class Player {
    constructor(input) {
        input.onkeypress = this.onkeyPress.bind(this); 
        this.keys_pressed = 0;
    }
    onkeyPress(event) {
      event.key=="w"? this.keys_pressed++:this.keys_pressed;
      console.log(this.keys_pressed);
    };
}

const input = document.querySelector("#input");
let p = new Player(input);
```

```html
Type here: <input type="text" id="input">
```